How to configure a PromQL query in Grafana to display network transmission data over 24 hours and 7 days?
I'm working on a Grafana dashboard and I would like to create a panel that displays the overall status of my application, specifically the number of gigabytes transmitted in the last 24 hours and the past 7 days. I'm using Prometheus as a data source with the metric container_network_transmit_bytes_total.
However, I am experiencing a problem with data consistency when I try to configure my PromQL query. Here is my current query for the last 24 hours:
sum(rate(container_network_transmit_bytes_total[24h]) * 86400)
This query does not seem to return the expected results, and I think I am not managing the aggregation or the time interval correctly.
Could you help me adjust my query to correctly display the data for 24-hour and 7-day periods? What would be the best way to structure this PromQL query to accurately reflect this data?
Thank you very much for your help!

Query seems correct to me. Why do you think it produces something wrong?

Because when i look at my cluster it indicates around 10Gb for the last 24 hours but on my panel it appears that it's around 250Gb
